# Riley Riddle #368

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

My prefix is a language - rather recently designed

My infix is a game - to exercise your mind

My suffix is a journey - a trial to undertake

My whole is all ready - proceed, a guess, to make

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here goes nothing:

My prefix is a language - rather recently designed

> The [**Go** programming language](https://go.dev/) was designed 15 years ago.

My infix is a game - to exercise your mind

> [**Go**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) is a traditional Eastern Asian board game.

My suffix is a journey - a trial to undertake

> A **go** can be a journey or an attempt at doing something.

My whole is all ready - proceed, a guess, to make

> All **go** means everything is ready. To **go** means to proceed. To have a **go** at means to try.
>
>  Yes, the prefix, infix and suffix all happen to be the whole word. They are affixed to nothing, or, as Go programmers would say, to the empty string.

Comment: Yep, that is correct. Also, according to some places, "go" has 368 definitions, hence the title.

Comment: Hello @Jason  Please do not disclose the answer in your comment. Put your comment in Rot13 or something.